# Merge only part of a Word document from Excel source

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

As the header suggests, I am trying use the MS Office merge functions to apply to a part of a Word document and not the entire document.

**Context:** I have a database in Excel with names and email addresses of recipients and use this as a source in MS Word. However, I have several languages in one single Word document. The recipient should only receive her own language and not all others. I had set up the Word document that way to avoid having several word documents named `Email_booking_FR.docx`, `Email_booking_EN.docx`, `Email_booking_NL.docx`, etc.
I have to say that the merge functions properly at the moment, with the limitation that the email sent contains all languages.

My Word document looks like this (Minimum Working Example):

```
EN

Dear Recipient,

Thank you for your email. We will get back to you as soon as possible.

Best,


FR

Cher Recipient,

Merci pour votre e-mail. Nous le traiterons dans les plus brefs délais.

Cordialement,
```

where `Recipient` is the field in the Excel worksheet.

**Objective:** 
I wuold like the merge function in MS Word to apply to the whole document (in other words, to complete all `Recipient` fields, but to send only part of the Word document as an email). Is this possible? Is Word capable of doing such things if the *EN* and *FR* parts are sections (`Title1` tags)

**From the following possibilities, which one(s) are (1) possible and (2) adequate?:**

- `If...then...else` statement within Word based on the language of the recipient in the Excel sheet
- Separate the languages by a page break (the problem of the Header *EN* or *FR* remains, however)
- Recover the line number of the specific sections and use it in a Macro (but I have no idea how)

Do you have more thoughts on the matter?

Comment: A quick point before commenting:  This looks to be a discussion piece, which is out of scope for SO.  I will vote as such.  If you have a determined path forward, please edit your post to limit the scope to a single, objective question.

Comment: I believe that, since you are needing Word to determine which text to insert (read that as *have logic*), you would need some VBA logic.  If you go the VBA route, remember that SO is not a code-for-you service, and a question tailored for VBA would need to have your attempted code and efforts.

Comment: Have you *tried* your approach, using an `If` field in the document? Theoretically, that should work.

Comment: @Cyril, thank you for your reply. I understand that SO is not an outsourcing platform for my coding needs, although I have seen many questions here that would fall in that category. My question was: among the three proposed paths, which are (1) possible and (2) adequate. From what I gather from your comment, only the VBA route respects both conditions.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I have not tried any of the three avenues because I did not know which ones were even possible. For example, I could _think_ that it is conceptually possible to get the line at which a certain string appears without being able to correctly use VBA to answer my needs. 
At any rate, thank you for your reply, I will investigate the `If´ statement.

Comment: Not that it's the easiest thing to review, but have you looked at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-rules-for-a-mail-merge-d546ee7e-ab7a-4d6d-b488-41f9e4bd1409 ?  You can set rules (if/else) for mail merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have a field in the mailmerge data source that identifies the language to be used, you could use a series of fields, coded along the lines of:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD Language}= "EN" "Dear «Recipient»,

Thank you for your email. We will get back to you as soon as possible.

Best,"}{IF{MERGEFIELD Language}= "NL" "Beste «Recipient»,

Bedankt voor je email. We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op.

Het beste,"}{IF{MERGEFIELD Language}= "FR" "Cher «Recipient»,

Merci pour votre e-mail. Nous le traiterons dans les plus brefs délais.

Cordialement,"}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

Note also that the output text cannot contain any double quotes; otherwise the output will be truncated at that point. Moreover, you are liable to have the remainder appearing in the other outputs! You can work around that by using paired single quotes.

You may also find my **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html helpful.

Comment: a big thank you to you! I was thinking about nested `If' but your solution works flawlessly. I have put our link in Favorites.
It even addresses the removal of page and line breaks.
A very complete answer.